# 3dtv application building .net

Tags: c#, animation, 3d, data-visualization

I'm looking for an SDK / tutorial on how I could build a 3dTV ready application.  The goal is to evaluate 3DTV capabilities for data visualization, and company brand advertising.   Although I've seen and worked with many 3D animation SDKs, I have yet to see one geared to broadcast/project through a 3DTV.  I'd prefer a .net SDK, but am willing to use any available development platform to evaluate the concept.

any Suggestions are appreciated..
Rob

Answer (score 1):

DirectX 11.1 has Stereoscopic 3D support built in, but if you wait for Windows 8, you can get a full stereo 3D api:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Direct3D-111-Simple-Stereo-9b2b61aa

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780567.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. would definitely look forward to the Win8 support.  But still interested knowing what's currently available, if anything...